# How to make number variable indicating the pair occurence by year in r?

Tags: r

I would like to make a variable `"whatiwant"` in the below `df3`.

Though I usually use `add_count`. `add_count` puts total count value in the variable, so it does not work for this case.

```
df1 <- data.frame(exporter = c("Laos", "Brazil", "USA"),
                  product = c("apple", "banana", "orange"),
                  year = 2010,
                  whatiwant = 1)

df2 <- data.frame(exporter = c("Laos", "Brazil", "Israel"),
                  product = c("apple", "banana", "grape"),
                  year = 2011,
                  whatiwant = c(2, 2, 1))

df3 <- rbind(df1, df2)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We may need `rowid`

```
library(data.table)
library(dplyr)
df3 %>%
    mutate(whatIwant2 = rowid(exporter, product))
```

-output

```
   exporter product year whatiwant whatIwant2
1     Laos   apple 2010         1          1
2   Brazil  banana 2010         1          1
3      USA  orange 2010         1          1
4     Laos   apple 2011         2          2
5   Brazil  banana 2011         2          2
6   Israel   grape 2011         1          1
```

---

Or use `base R`

```
df3$whatIwant2 <- with(df3, ave(seq_along(exporter), exporter, 
     product, FUN = seq_along))
```

Answer (score 1):

With `dplyr`, you can use `row_number()` by groups of `exporter` and `product`.

```r
library(dplyr)

df3 %>%
  mutate(whatIwant2 = row_number(), .by = c(exporter, product))

#   exporter product year whatiwant whatIwant2
# 1     Laos   apple 2010         1          1
# 2   Brazil  banana 2010         1          1
# 3      USA  orange 2010         1          1
# 4     Laos   apple 2011         2          2
# 5   Brazil  banana 2011         2          2
# 6   Israel   grape 2011         1          1
```